# ( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Route' not found in C:\wamp\www\untitled1\routes\api.php on line 16

Tags: laravel-5, routes, windows-7, wamp, phpstorm-2017.1

i get this error when i'm using laravel with phpstorm ,wamp server 
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZk18.png)

could you please help me ,thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not installed the composer file dependencies. Try to do a `composer install`
On your project directory where the *composer.json* file should exist.

If you haven't already installed composer, follow the instructions at composer site.

Comment: i get this error 

  Problem 1
    - doctrine/inflector v1.2.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - doctrine/inflector v1.2.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for doctrine/inflector v1.2.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[v1.2.0].

Process finished with exit code 2 at 12:02:43.

Comment: Can you post a copy of your composer.json file? It seems that you need to have php 7 installed on your server, but you could choose a version of your composer dependencies that satisfies your 5.6.25 php version. 

You can do it reviewing each dependency shown in your composer.json file comparing them in https://packagist.org/ and finding a lower compatible version.

Comment: sir, could you please give me your mail so we can contact rapidly

Comment: yes, for sure, i wrote you at esi.dz please check your messages.